# Admin redirect to domine.com/admin from domine.com/app/admin after login

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, webfaction

Hi I've got a problem my problem is that I Have two apps in the same domine:

```
mydomine.com     it has the first app loaded.
mydomine.com/app2/ it has the second one loaded
```

If i go to :

```
mydomine.com/app2/admin
```

I'm able to log in but after I log in the admin redirects me to:

```
mydomine.com/admin
```

And I want to be redirected to:

```
mydomine.com/app2/admin
```

Does anybody knows why this happen? How can I fix it?

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer myself because I found the answer and maybe it can be helpful for another person:

[The answer from WebFaction](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/config.html#mounting-a-django-application-on-a-subpath) is that I had to add [FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#force-script-name) variable to my settings and the value of this one in my case has to be `app2`

Answer (score 0):

when you are using url always put `/` at begining and end. for eg:-

```
<a href="/<url>/">testing</a>
```

or in Httpresponse as

```
HttpResponseRedirect('/<url>/')
```

Comment: Yes  I have that but the problem is from the admin.

Comment: don't know much aboutit. check admin's `views.py` or some thing for `HttpResponseRedirect('/<url>/')` and change it if nesseary